# Is there any best way to implement Encryption in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, encryption, flex3, secret-key

we have one application where we are pulling some confidential information from one of the product design tools. So we have used HTTPS as the channel and also we are encrypting the Request Parameters and Some data before we sent it to Web Services. So, Everything seems OK.

But when we gave the application for Security auditing they found we have hard coded the encryption key in source code. They have used Sothink SWF Decompiler to look into my SWF file. They caught the key and raised concern over it.

We have developed this application using Flex 3(SDK 3.4). Is there any best way to use Secret key without being hard coded in source code. If anybody come across this kind of problem, please let me know.

Anyone, please suggest me the best way to use the secret keys in SourceCode without being Hard coded.

Here is my sample code:

```
var currentResult:String = "";
        var strDataToEncrypt:String = "";
        var kdata:ByteArray;

        var todayDate:Date = new Date();

        kdata = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString("secretKey here"));
        strDataToEncrypt =username.toUpperCase() + "#$#" + password + "#$#"  + todayDate.getTime().toString();          
        var data:ByteArray;
        data = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(strDataToEncrypt))
        var name:String = "des3-ecb";
        var pad:IPad = new PKCS5; 
        var mode:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher(name, kdata, pad);
        pad.setBlockSize(mode.getBlockSize());
        mode.encrypt(data);
        currentResult = Base64.encodeByteArray(data);
        var token:String = currentResult;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as complete protection with Flash.  Your keys have to be either in the code or loaded externally, and at some point anyone who is determined enough will be able to get them.  All you can do is make this process so complex that it's not worth the hassle.

Have a look at this question for ways to make your source harder to decompile and read: [How to protect swf file from being decompiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251651/how-to-protect-swf-file-from-being-decompiled)

Comment: I have tried few Obfuscaters and Encryptors. Still Sothink decompiler was able to decompile it. Is there any good Obfuscator and Encryptor is available? Please suggest me few.

Answer (score 0):

don't send your data as url parameters. send it with a post request.

if that's not possible you could try implementing a scheme with a public key. but be careful, chances are high that you implement something wrong which leads to even bigger security problems.

Comment: I am using post with HTTPS channel only. But still they want us to encrypt any data before we send it to server. Because we are exchanging some product design related information.

Comment: um ok...then look into PKI..or diffie hellmann or something like that.. but IMHO it doesn't make any sense, if you don't have a PhD in security you only create security problems. because your implementation will always be much weaker than say SSL.

Comment: and where is this swf being executed? on a trusted host? then use vpn/ssl or something similar. if it's on a untrusted host you don't have any security at all.. somewhere plain text will be stored in any case.

Comment: It's getting executed in secured environment only.  It's completely intranet faced application and this is protected by a firewall from outside access. Only thing is, if anybody gets my SWF file, they will be able to decompile and they can see the Key. So that they can decrypt the session also. That's why security raised a concern.

Comment: We are planning for a work around for now, Like We will keep the Secret key in the server. Once the user successfully login with their LDAP id's we will give the secret key to the user. As the link is encrypted, it can have some protection. Any suggestions and any comments on this workaround?